# Wordpress Redirect Loop Error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, loops, redirect

Had a dev build a theme for wordpress. The site is beonpointe.com - have tried to make it live and the url just redirects to /index1.html - there is no domain forwarding with the host, neither is there any domain forwarding in the HTACCESS.

I found a snippet in the theme's functions.php, but uncommented it to see if it would work, and it still doesn't. Please could anyone help?!

The code snippet was:

```
<?php 
define('TEMPLATE_DOMAIN', 'beonpointe'); 
define('BOP_IS_LIVE', 'true'); 

function only_admin_access(){ 
    if( BOP_IS_LIVE == 'true' ): 
        if( !is_user_logged_in() ): 
            wp_redirect( site_url('') ); 
        endif; 
    endif; 
}
add_action('wp_top_head', 'only_admin_access'); 
?>
```

It would be much appreciated. I thank you in advance.

Comment: What about [home_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
define('TEMPLATE_DOMAIN', 'beonpointe'); 
define('BOP_IS_LIVE', 'true'); 

function only_admin_access(){ 
    if( BOP_IS_LIVE == 'true' ): 
        if( !is_user_logged_in() ): 
           wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
           exit;
        endif; 
    endif; 
}
add_action('wp_top_head', 'only_admin_access'); 
?>
```

[More info ro redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to wp-config.php:

```
 $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```